# Is there a way to convert shader graph to shader code for older version?

Tags: unity, shaders

Editing Shader in a graph is brilliant feature, however it's only works in Unity 2018 with Lightweight RP template.

So I want to use the shader made from shader graph in Unity 2018 to older versions, such as 2017 or 5.x.

There is a button to compile the shader to code but unfortunately when I drag into 2017 it gives me syntax error so I can't use it.

Is there a way to use the shader made from Unity 2018's graph editor to older versions of Unity?

Comment: I mentioned this Issue on github's project and Peter Bay Bastian tell me `We'll be adding in the option to open shader code ala surface shaders, but it won't be possible to have those changes reflected back. For now, you can open the graph, right click the master node and select "Copy shader".`

Comment: I recommend you  [shaderforge](http://www.acegikmo.com/shaderforge/) because It's free to use and open source also It haven't any bug like ShaderGraph